# Не получается установить поддержку c# в emacs

Tags: c#, emacs

Нужно установить в emacs поддержку c#, я пробовал курить мануалы на гитхабе, пытался ставить и csharp mode и omnisharp. Конкретно не работает шаг M-x package-install RET csharp-mode RET. Пишет "No matches". Как с одним, так ис другим. Emacs я ещё не умею толком пользоваться, даже лиспа не знаю, но это единственная полу-ide, с которой можно пользоваться по ssh

Comment: Лучше не стоит. Есть visual studio code

Comment: Vscode не работает в терминале

Comment: Посмотрите как ставить. Melpa репозиторий